# Delete mass action for admin grid not working

Tags: magento2

Delete mass action for admin grid not working

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\First\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 element(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment this loop

```
    /*foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $item->delete();
    }*/
```

And add below code

```
$recordDeleted=0;
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $deleteItem = $this->_objectManager->get('Vt\First\Model\Post')->load($item->getId());
        $deleteItem->delete();
        $recordDeleted++;
    }
```

Make sure to add this in your Model Collection file

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'post_id';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 chage your for loop
 foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $model=$this->registrationFactory->create()->load($item->getId());
        $model->delete();
    }
```